# Mathematical puzzle 003

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

[image: Mathematical puzzle question 003]

I saw [this question](https://14773644510176710490.googlegroups.com/attach/451fe8c534a87/IMG_3457.jpg?part=0.1&view=1&view=1&vt=ANaJVrFJb0Mmcspj__cFN9Dqk-sWrRMi68On5EsgNtzj93EmF_s70PYf76SbukE7b_tkfOtyx_HT45yNNVp9AC2DHm3YFoo_wKYkvukKjBWCLvq5PlA6gAQ) on [Math group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tmoz/M5WXGW-0if4) and tried to solve it question to no avail. I approached it by taking the square of the first row, adding it to the second, then subtracting the fourth row from the result to get third row as answer, but I couldn't make any connection between the rows. Each time I try to make one but it doesn't suit for other columns. These questions belong to YÖS exam and I think the book is [YÖS questions by Kuark publications](https://www.yargiyayinevi.com/yos-yabanci-uyruklu-ogrenci-sinavi/kuark-yayinlari-yos-genel-yetenek-iq-soru-bankasi). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st column: 43 - 6^2 = 7

2nd column: 78 - 8^2 = 14

3rd column: 29 - 5^2 = 4

4th column: 58 - 7^2 = 9

So, the correct answer is A.

Comment: A is A. Imagine that.

Comment: I wasn't correcting you. I did not notice the error in your post. I was simply observing that the question was "A=?" and the answer is "A". I found that amusing.